# List of all published books for Chronicles of Darkness Second Edition

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

Is there a comprehensive list somewhere of all published works for Chronicles of Darkness, 2nd Edition?

I've tried Onyx Publishing but I am having trouble finding a complete listing of only second edition books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put this forward: DriveThruRPG.

Navigating to DriveThruRPG, you can select Onyx Path from the list of publishers.

At that point, you can select a sub-category. If the category has a red outline and Ouroboros in the lower right corner, it's new content for the "Vampire the Masquerade"-headed classic World of Darkness.

If it has a "WoD" in the lower right corner, it's the "Blue book core + gameline core" new World of Darkness (renamed Chronicles of Darkness) that ran up until Mummy: The Curse.

But, if it has a "CoD" in the lower right corner, it's a Chronicles of Darkness Second Edition book - DriveThru considers only books that have "Chronicles of Darkness" in print as included in CoD. The union of each title in each CoD section serves as a solid list that includes all CoD 2nd books.

There's only a couple drawbacks: First is that not all titles are books - eg, Condition cards or posters.

The second is that this isn't a list of all CoD books - this is a list of all CoD books currently under publication. For example, at this time, DriveThru doesn't offer any core book for Geist: The Sin-Eaters, since the second edition is not yet published.

At this point in time, the second edition Chronicles of Darkness is a currently published line from Onyx Path, so I still feel this is a solid list; but this method may not be reliable when CoD: 2nd Ed is not an actively published line.